# Add a list to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Right now I'm writing a function that reads data from a file, with the goal being to add that data to a numpy array and return said array.

I would like to return the array as a 2D array, however I'm not sure what the complete shape of the array will be (I know the amount of columns, but not rows). 
What I have right now is:

```
columns = _____
for line in currentFile:
     currentLine = line.split()
     data = np.zeros(shape=(columns),dtype=float)
     tempData = []
     for i in range(columns):
          tempData.append(currentLine[i])
      data = np.concatenate((data,tempdata),axis=0)
```

However, this makes a 1D array.

Essentially what I'm asking is:

Is there any way to have add a python list as a row to a numpy array with a variable amount of rows?

Comment: Don't even bother reading it by hand like this, you can simply use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to read write into a numpy array. Similarly you can use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt)

Answer (score 1):

If your file `data.txt` is

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

All you need to do is

```
>>> import numpy as n
>>> data_array = n.loadtxt("data.txt")
>>> data_array

array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the common way of constructing an array:

```
np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
np.array([[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9]])
```

The input is a list of lists.  Your reader could imitate that

Roughly:

```
data = []
for line in f.readline():
    values = line.strip().split(',')
    values = [int(v) for v in values]
    data.append(values)
data = np.array(data)
```

`np.loadtxt` and `np.genfromtxt` do essentially that, just with more bells and whistles.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify @Abstracted 's solution as:

```
data_array = np.loadtxt("data.txt", dtype =int)
```

you will get the array in integer form if you want it that way.